# Multiple polygons on the map

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, google-maps-android-api-2

I managed to draw one polygon on the map. Code I used:

```
private void drawPolygons() {

    PolygonOptions polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions();
    polygonOptions.addAll(arrayPolygon);
    polygonOptions.strokeColor(Color.CYAN);
    polygonOptions.strokeWidth(4);
    polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.CYAN);
    Polygon polygon = googleMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);

}
```

I am trying to draw another one. I tried like this:

```
private void drawPolygons() {

    PolygonOptions polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions();
    polygonOptions.addAll(arrayPolygon);
    polygonOptions.addAll(arrayPolygonSecond);
    polygonOptions.strokeColor(Color.CYAN);
    polygonOptions.strokeWidth(4);
    polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.CYAN);
    Polygon polygon = googleMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);

}
```

Those two LatLng Arrays just got messed up (vertices from both Arrays got connected). I need those two polygons separated.

Any help would be appreciated a lot. Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. I had to make two separated functions. Here is the code:

```
private void drawPolygons() {

    PolygonOptions polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions();
    polygonOptions.addAll(arrayPolygonOne);
    polygonOptions.strokeColor(Color.CYAN);
    polygonOptions.strokeWidth(4);
    polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.CYAN);
    Polygon polygon = googleMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);

}

private void drawPolygonsOne() {

    PolygonOptions polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions();
    polygonOptions.addAll(arrayPolygonOne);
    polygonOptions.strokeColor(Color.CYAN);
    polygonOptions.strokeWidth(4);
    polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.CYAN);
    Polygon polygon = googleMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This my code, dynamic draw multiple polygon area:

```
List<LatLng> allArea;  

for(HeadArea area : data.getListHeadAreas()) {
      allArea = new ArrayList<>();

      for(DetailArea detailArea : area.getDetailAreas()) {
         allArea.add(new LatLng(detailArea.getLatitude(), detailArea.getLongitude()));
      }

      mMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
          .addAll(PolyUtil.simplify(allArea, 3))
          .fillColor(Color.RED)
          .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
          .strokeWidth(3));
}
```